# How can a Laravel package filter all requests and redirect if necessary?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, package, before-filter

I would like to build a package for Laravel 4 that checks for some specific parameters and redirects the request to another url if needed.

Is there a best way to do that?

I would prefer to have the package able to simply be dropped in and configured without having to modify the filters or routes files in the base Laravel install.

Comment: If you know the routes your package would filter (related to your package) then it' fine otherwise the developer have to write codes.

Comment: It would be all routes. The whole site needs to be able to be filtered, and potentially redirected elsewhere if certain parameters were true.

Comment: Then use pattern matching filter like `when('*', 'filter')` and give the option to enable/disable filters using `config`.

Comment: Where do I add that filter in the package though?

Comment: Depends on your package, how do I know?

Comment: Maybe I should clarify my question... can someone point me to an article or tutorial explaining how to hook up packages in laravel to the filtering capabilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to do it simply put:

You can do a pre request processing by registering `before` [application events](http://laravel.com/docs/lifecycle#application-events) to for a global filtering of responses sake like so:

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    //
});
```

You have to register it in one of your [start files](http://laravel.com/docs/lifecycle#start-files) or in a [service provider](http://laravel.com/docs/ioc#service-providers).

---

### Package recommended for study:

I strongly recommend you to delve into [Laravel-Hooks](https://github.com/ChuckHeintzelman/Laravel-Hooks), a Laravel 4 package by Chuck Heintzelman.

You should focus on the `app/start/onbefore.php` hook, executed as global app "before" filters.

Excerpt:

```
/**
 * Set up before listener if found
 */
protected function registerOnBefore()
{
    $file = $this->hookName('onbefore');
    if ($file)
    {
        $this->app->before(function ($request) use ($file)
        {
            $result = static::load($this->app, $file, compact('request'));
            if ($result !== 1)
            {
                return $result;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Stripped from [Laravel-Hooks/src/Heintzelman/LaravelHooks/LaravelHooksServiceProvider.php](https://github.com/ChuckHeintzelman/Laravel-Hooks/blob/master/src/Heintzelman/LaravelHooks/LaravelHooksServiceProvider.php#L95).

Don't forget to share your findings :-)

Comment: Thank you very much! That's the sort of answer I was looking for. I didn't realize I could just extend the App::before() call in that way. I come from a WordPress background and it sounds like the Laravel-Hooks work a lot like WP actions and filters.